# Instantiate an arbitrary class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSMutableArray of objects in Objective C. I'm filling this up based on the contents of a data file, which contains the class each element should be and a list of parameters. All of the possible classes inherit from a common parent class.

Is there any way of instantiating each element of the array without hard-coding each of the possible classes inside a massive if-else test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You currently store the name of the class in the data file as well as the object's parameters.

You can therefore use `NSClassFromString` to instantiate that custom class object and initialize its state:

```
NSString *_myCustomClass = // get custom class name from data file...
id _myCustomObject = [[NSClassFromString(_myCustomClass) alloc] init];
// set up _myCustomObject's state from data file's parameters...
[_myMutableArray addObject:_myCustomObject];
[_myCustomObject release];
```

Comment: +1 spot on answer. Is it worth mentioning how you'd get the selector for a particular property (by name?) in order to set its value?

Comment: @Rob - if the properties were declared using `@property`, then the simplest answer would be to use `setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: Even if the properties were not declared using `@property`, you can still use `setValue:forKey:` Key-Value coding predated Objective-C 2.0's `@property` declarations and searches for appropriately named setter(s) followed by direct ivar assignment.

Comment: What about custom `init` methods?

Answer (score -1):

If you're in control of writing that data file too, you might find it easier to just use standard objective C [archiving](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html) (called serialization in other languages). It's an easy way to write and read objects into and from a file.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I guess memset() will be of help